# not to minify the js when degugging the code minify-maven-plugin samaxes

Tags: javascript, maven

I am using minify-maven-plugin of com.samaxes.maven to minify my js files and to make package into a single file. But during the development/debugging i need to set a configuration so that it does not minify the js but still packages the js in a single file. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://samaxes.github.io/minify-maven-plugin/minify-mojo.html#skipMinify) as of 1.5.2 you can specify

```
<skipMinify>true</skipMinify>
```

If you use a property then you can provide a default value in the pom and override it on the command line. Or you could use a clever combination of profiles and their activations to automatically set it depending on your environment (for example, CI vs development).